# Did Neelix ever take/steal warp plasma from Voyager?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, warp

In season 3 episode 13 (Fair Trade) of Voyager, does Neelix ever actually take warp plasma from voyager?

From watching the episode, I understand that he "couldn't" and was given low-quality warp plasma from Bahrak to use instead, yet then in episode 23 of that season (Distant Origin), near the start of the episode is seems that an alien race acquires warp plasma from that trade station. Is this just an inconsistency, did the warp plasma come from elsewhere, or is it giving a false impression of it being from Voyager?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Neelix didn't use any of Voyager's warp plasma in "[VOY : Fair Trade](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/309.htm)". Bahrat provided him with a dummy sample:

> **NEELIX:** *You'll have to provide us with a sample of warp plasma. **I won't take any from Voyager.***
>
> **BAHRAT:** *What I can give you won't be of the same quality.*
>
> **NEELIX:** *Doesn't matter. We'll make do.*

That being the case, the most likely source of the Warp Plasma sample that the Voth manage to acquire in [VOY : Distant Origin](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/318.htm) is from the Captain's negotations with the Tak Tak in [VOY : Macrocosm](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/307.htm) since we see the canister being given to the Voth by a Tak Tak trader.

> **GEGEN** [OC]: *Our most significant find, a canister of warp plasma from Voyager's
>   engines. So now we are scanning space for a matching signature. Little
>   is known about these explorers, but they call themselves human.*

[image]

Comment: I don't see any reference to a warp plasma sample in that episode, only that the heat from the plasma can't be dissipated

Comment: @user2813274 - We can infer it from the fact that Voyager traded with them, then later we see a Tak Tak trader handing over some plasma. 1+1=2

Comment: Thanks for the picture, I didn't recognize the person as a Tak Tak until you pointed it out.